# Problem using collection package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, collections

If I run this code

```
print(CombinedMapView([{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]));
```

in Dart it prints as expected

```
{a: 1}
```

but in Flutter it prints

```
{a: 1, a: 1}
```

Is there a bug or did I miss something?

Comment: I tried, the result is same `{a: 1, a: 1}` both Dart and Flutter

Comment: @mducc but it should be `{a: 1}` in both cases.